# How to get rid of creation of "=0" file while running a shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a shell script which asks the user as how many number of files are there in the current working directory.

I have created the script in desktop location and when I ran the script it is working fine, but when I copy and paste it in anyother folder and if I try to run, it is creating a file with name "=0".

I have posted the script too, could any one help me in resolving this issue.

```
#!/bin/bash

numfiles=$(ls | wc -l)

try=1
read -p "Guess the number of files present in the directory: : " num_dir

while [ $num_dir>=0 ]
do
   if [ $try != 1 ]
   then
    read -p "Guess the number of files present in the directory: : " num_dir
   fi

   if [ $num_dir == $numfiles ]
   then
    exit
   elif [ $num_dir -gt $numfiles ]
    then
     echo "num_dir is greater than numfiles"    
   else
    echo "num_dir is less than numfiles"
   fi

   try=0

done
```

Comment: try `while [[ $num_dir >= 0 ]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in `while [ $num_dir>=0 ]` The condition redirects the "output" of `$num_dir` to the file `=0`.

You need

```
while [ $num_dir -ge 0 ]
```

Or the Bash-specific

```
while [[ $num_dir >= 0 ]]
```

Comment: `>=` only works in arithmetic expressions inside `((...))` or `$((...))`; you still need `-ge` inside `[[ ... ]]`.

Answer (score 2):

`test` doesn't have a `>=` operator; it's being parsed as an output redirection, equivalent to

```
[ $num_dir > =0 ]
```

or

```
[ $num_dir ] > =0
```

(redirections are recognized by the operator, before arguments to the command are identified).

For numerical comparision, use `-ge`:

```
# Quote to avoid a syntax error if num_dir has an empty value
[ "$num_dir" -ge 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
while true
```

this way you don't get the unwanted file, also user input can be 0 which would end your loop and you can get rid of `try`